# Standalone java Glasshfish client. Reference to gf-client.jar

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, ejb

i'm deploying an application making use of EJB. I'have wrote an EJB and a java standalone client to connect to. Everything works correctly.
However, i have a question regarding the JAR dependencies. I'm using Netbeans 7.1.2 and Glassfish 3.1.2 and the jars i have added to my client application are:

1. appserv-rt.jar
2. javaee.jar
3. gf-client.jar

I have read from here : http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#StandaloneRemoteEJB, than gf-client.jar hold by itself lot of dependencies. After looking at the MANIFEST file inside it, i saw that it provides lot of relatives path to others jars and then, i HAVE TO refer this jar directly in the glassfish installation path. This is not acceptable if i want to distribute this application to clients, all the clients using the application (client) would need to download Glassfish?

So my question is, how can i handle that? Is there a way to avoid referring directly gf-client.jar from the glassfish install path?

Comment: you might want to have a look at what is called the ACC (Application Client Container).
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beakv.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks,

i have solved my issue by adding those jars to my project:

auto-depends.jar 
deployment-common.jar
glassfish-corba-internal-api.jar
internal-api.jar
management-api.jar
bean-validator.jar
dol.jar
glassfish-corba-newtimer.jar  
 javax.ejb.jar
orb-connector.jar
common-util.jar
ejb-container.jar
glassfish-corba-omgapi.jar  
javax.jms.jar
orb-iiop.jar
config-api.jar
ejb.security.jar
glassfish-corba-orb.jar
javax.resource.jar
security.jar
config-types.jar
glassfish-api.jar
glassfish-corba-orbgeneric.jar   
javax.servlet.jar 
ssl-impl.jar
config.jar
glassfish-corba-asm.jar
glassfish-naming.jar
javax.transaction.jar
transaction-internal-api.jar
connectors-internal-api.jar     
glassfish-corba-codegen.jar     
gmbal.jar
jta.jar
container-common.jar
glassfish-corba-csiv2-idl.jar  
hk2-core.jar
kernel.jar

I don't think all the jars are needed in some case. Hope it would help.

Comment: where did you get the list of jars?

Answer (score 1):

In found this in [Application Development Guide](https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/application-development-guide.pdf):

> Copy the **as-install/lib/gf-client.jar** file to the client machine and include it in the classpath on the client side.
>
> The gf-client.jar file references GlassFish Server JAR files in its
> MANIFEST.MF file. If there is no GlassFish Server installation on the client machine, you must also copy the **as-install/modules** directory to the client machine and maintain its directory structure relative to the
> as-install /lib/gf-client.jar file. Or you can use the package-appclient
> script; see Using the package-appclient Script.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider Java Web Start and let GlassFish decide for himself what dependencies the client local ACC must use. These will be automatically downloaded by the client.

I wrote a tutorial on how to write a JavaFX application who is launched through Java Web Start and uses dependency injection for a proxy to a server side resource:

[The Enterprise Side of JavaFX: The Missing Part](http://blog.martinandersson.com/the-enterprise-side-of-javafx-the-missing-part/).